# Find how many classes there are in a specific elemenet

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got this piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.parent >' + '.child').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).length);
    });
});
```

And i'm trying to log how many classes of `child` there are in the `parent` class.

This is what my html code looks like:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Expected output**:

```
5
```

**Actual output**:

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: use "i" in each and then get value of "i" see my ans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just

```
var elementsLength = $('.parent > .child').length
```

When you iterate you get the length of each element, which is 1 as it's one element at a time

***EDIT:***

I'm a little lost, but based on the comments below something like

```
$('.parent').each(function() {

    var elementsLength = $(this).children('.child').length

    if (elementsLength > 12) $(this).hide();

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/37G8x/)

***EDIT, AGAIN :***

To hide just the overflowing elements is even easier

```
$('.parent .child:gt(12)').hide();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/37G8x/1/)

Comment: I did right? But i want a function to be executed when every `parent`'s `child` has been found. So how would i do that then without the `each` function?

Comment: Not sure I get it, why don't you post the actual problem you're having instead ?

Comment: I did, but i did not expect i didnt have to use the `each` function. Because i want to do something with the result.

@webkit How then?

Comment: you want to do something with each element or with the length? you have to clarify what you want..

Comment: I want to check if the length of that number is higher then 12. If so, hide the `parent` element

Comment: So basically hide all `.parent` with more than 12 `.children` ?

Comment: @adeneo Yeah, how would i do that then?

Comment: @Dreiba See my ans if you use "i" in each it will give you loop number if your loop number will more then 12 means you have 12 child elements!

Comment: @Sid That doesnt really work, but this one did. Thanks, accepting answer in a min

Comment: @adeneo Is it possible to hide only the overflow aswell? So when there are 13 `child`s, but only the 13th gets hidden?

Comment: @Dreiba You'd have better to ask a new question instead of asking new question in comment unrelevant to opening question

Answer (score 1):

You can Do this Using **Find()** and **Length**

$(".parent").find(".child").length

and If You want to user it in **EACH**
then

```
$('.parent').find('.child').each(function(i) {
        console.log(i);
        if(i==12)
        {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

Where **"i"** will be element number in your code

Answer (score 0):

Use the length property:

```
console.log( $('.parent >' + '.child').length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
             console.log($('.parent').childrens('.child').length);
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var elemlength = $('.parent .child').length;
```

Comment: Provide some Explanation so that it is easier for the OP to understand

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery selector actually returns an array of DOM elements, so you can run length directly on the selector:

```
$('.parent > .child').length; //Returns 5
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3NMAG/